# Ignore null enum values using System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, system.text.json

I am in the process of migrating to System.Text.Json from Newtonsoft. One of the things we were doing was that were ignoring any null values in the request body while deserializing.

What I am observing is that if the incoming request JSON has a null value assigned for an enum property, the deserialization fails. It doesn't seem to ignore it. How can I avoid that? Ideally we want to mimic the functionality of Newtonsoft's "NullValueHandling.Ignore" property.

I am already setting the "DefaultIgnoreCondition" to "JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull", but it doesnt help. Here is the snippet:

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x =>
{
    // serialize enums as strings in api responses
    x.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
    x.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
    x.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
});
```

I would appreciate any help on this. My API project is targeting .NET 6.0

Comment: Please provide a minimum example of the given JSON and the target class, with the enum property.

Comment: What do you want to use as the value when `null` is encountered? `default(TEnum)`?

Comment: @dbc I would want it to behave the same as if its not there at all. When I remove it from the request JSON, it works. When its present with null value it fails

Comment: You would need to declare the property as nullable `public YourEnum? SomeProperty` For the record JSON.Net doesn't parse it either.

Comment: JSON.NET seems to work without declaring the property as nullable - not exactly sure how

Comment: Hello have you tried the solution provided?  Is there anything else that I can help you on this?

Answer (score 2):

> What I am observing is that if the incoming request JSON has a null
> value assigned for an enum property, the deserialization fails. It
> doesn't seem to ignore it. How can I avoid that?

As [@charlieface](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14868997/charlieface) already mentioned in comment, thus, I am amplifying further.  Actually, the first thing you need to consider while ignoring serialization is nullability.

In other words, the ignoring property should be null. Because, if you set  [WhenWritingDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/ignore-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0#ignore-all-null-value-properties) or NullValueHandling.Ignore to a non nullable property model binder will not ignore that as it will be treated as required. Thus, evaluation became self-contradictory.

Let's have a look in practice:

Demo Enum and Model:

```cs
[System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public enum NullEnumTest
    {
        Unknown,
        None,
        RecordNotFound,
        FileNotFound
    }

public class EnumNullTestClass
    {
     
        public string FileName { get; set; }
       
        public NullEnumTest? NullEnumTest { get; set; }

    }
```

**Note:** I made Template property as nullable by putting `NullEnumTest?` You can check here, [ignoring property always be nullable.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/ignore-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0#ignore-all-null-value-properties)

Program.cs:

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{

    options.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;

});
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details [how to Ignore all null-value properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/ignore-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0#ignore-all-null-value-properties) during runtime you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/ignore-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0#ignore-all-null-value-properties)

Comment: Thanks, not sure how but Newtonsoft seems to work without the need for making the enum nullable

Comment: Without nullable type `JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull` will  not work no matter which  Serialization method you would be using. Have a look on the Microsoft document I have referred which is explicitely using nullable for `JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull`